# GAE datastore - count records between one minute ago and two minutes ago?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GAE datastore with python and I want to count and display the number of records between two recent dates. for examples, how many records exist with a time signature between two minutes ago and three minutes ago in the datastore.
Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from datetime import datetime

class Voice(db.Model):
    when = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        voices = db.GqlQuery(
            'SELECT * FROM Voice '
            'ORDER BY when DESC')
        values = {
            'voices': voices
        }
        self.response.out.write(template.render('main.html', values))
    def post(self):
        voice = Voice()
        voice.put()
        self.redirect('/')
        self.response.out.write('posted!')  

def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
        (r'.*', MyHandler)], debug=True)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines:
q = db.Query().filter('when >', current date - x minutes)
return q.count() ...

Comment: Yeah you seem to be on the right path. Construct a query with filters for "> two_minutes_ago" and "< one_minute_ago" and return the count. Are you having problems writing the query? The code you posted isn't very specific.

Comment: Thank you Jason. You understood perfectly. This is what we have so far: --- --- 

voices = db.Query(Voice).filter(???).count(); --- ---
What we are not sure about is how to write the condition with the correct dates for x minutes ago.
Could you write an example as an answer? I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: What's the relevance of the big chunk of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count = db.Query().filter('when >', two_minutes_ago).filter('when <', one_minute_ago).count()
```

You can learn more about queries in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass).

To get the values of `two_minutes_ago` and `one_minute_ago` you can use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14, 14, 26, 18, 343269)
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14, 14, 25, 49, 860390)
```

Try it out in your Python REPL to get more familiar with it.

Comment: How do I calculate the value of two_minutes_ago? I've never done this before and that is the part that confuses me?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped us out here. Where could we learn more on our own?

Comment: Read the docs (http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) and try things out using the Python command-line tool.

Comment: Hi, it works in Python Shell but it doesn't work in GAE right now?
    one_minute_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1);
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: This sounds like an import problem. Does your code include `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime`? (These behave differently)

Comment: from datetime import datetime

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10082/discussion-between-jason-hall-and-arthur-wulf-white)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will require a composite index to support the ordering by date. This means that any recent updates will be eventually consistent. The most recent updates may not show because of this. Love to hear about any workarounds.

Comment: No it won't - you can sort or filter on a single property without any composite indexes. Results will be eventually consistent regardless, though.